# How can I use bootstrap with wordpress & woocommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

I've made websites from scratch using bootstrap and websites using wordpress but now I want to make an e-commerce website using wordpress and woocommerce but I also want to utilise bootrap's commands for responsiveness. How can I integrate bootstrap into my wordpress theme that I am creating?

Comment: Please narrow down your question to the specific problem. Your question is too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your theme/child-theme functions.php file you should enqueue your css and javascript files.

For example:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {


   wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-theme-style', '/wp-content/themes/' . get_stylesheet() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-min-script', '/wp-content/themes/' . get_stylesheet() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the bootstrap styles and javascript to the theme header and then use the responsive classes described in:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: It is a bad practice to put javascript in header. Additionnaly, foor wordpress, I remember there are `wp_` functions that handle javascript.

Comment: It is not a bad practice if it is your custom template.

Comment: the accepted answer is what i meant. +1 for custom facts