# Bootstrap Collapse: Only one panel at a time (possible jQuery library issue)

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

I am trying to implement Bootstrap collapsible panels on my website, but something isn't working properly. My intention is to change the default WooCommerce tabs to collapsing panels/accordions. Here is the code I used to override WooCommerce's tabs.php file:

```
<?php
/**
* Single Product tabs
*
* @author WooThemes
* @package WooCommerce/Templates
* @version 2.0.0
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

/**
* Filter tabs and allow third parties to add their own
*
* Each tab is an array containing title, callback and priority.
* @see woocommerce_default_product_tabs()
*/
$tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );

if (!empty($tabs)):
?>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

  <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" role="button" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-<?php echo $key ?>" class="collapsed">
          <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', $tab['title'], $key ) ?>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-<?php echo $key ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <?php call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ) ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>

<?php 
endif;
?>
</div><!-- .summary -->
```

The panels are working well, the only exception being that I cannot have just one panel open at a time. If I try toggling a second panel, the others don't collapse as they should. I have successfully implemented the panels before, but now something clearly is off.

I suspect it might be related to the jQuery library as it is not included anywhere at this point. I tried using both `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` but to no avail.

Fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4oow595w/) (please note: I have removed the PHP code and inserted some dummy text for the panel title and content. In my case, I will have just 2 panels, not 3).

Any advice?

Update: Here's the outputted HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/e2vc545g/ (I cannot add the entire HTML code of the webpage as it exceeds 3,000 characters)

Comment: the Jquery lib is req'd for bootstrap to fully function

Comment: @happymacarts As per my original post, I tried to do it several ways but to no avail. Any suggestion for the code I should include in my header.php? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure your jQuery is not loading? from your console try this `$.fn.jquery`. You may also try to download a copy of jquery lib and put it local on your server (in yours __scripts__ or __js__  folder)

Comment: your fiddle had some markup issues I copied the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) version modified it and pasted it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mendchhw/) I think that is working as you intended

Comment: Can you paste the rendered php of that page here so we can see what is going on with it?

Comment: It seems the real question may be answered [here ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666556/how-can-i-use-bootstrap-with-wordpress-woocommerce)

Comment: @happymacarts I replaced the markup with yours and it isn't working. The behaviour is the same. I embedded the same jQuery library and also the bootstrap.min.js file from the fiddle. What do you mean by 'rendered php'?

Comment: when you load that page in your browser the php engine process all your php code and sends a final version to the browser in only html format that the user views. it can be found by looking at you document inspector and copying the html content from the **source tab** or right click and **view source** depending on which  browser the commands may vary

Comment: A side note: I looked into the content between the `<head></head>` tags and I found this: http:/www.mysiteurl.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 Does this mean jQuery is already embedded on my site? Disclaimer: It's my first WP theme so I'm not very familiar with this.

Comment: It would have been easier to say outputted HTML rather than rendered PHP. Here's the code: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/y7359a7a/) I replaced the text with dummy text.

Comment: so the link you posted to the fiddle is that what you see when you go to the webpage?

Comment: the most recent jsfiddle has a script tag nested inside of another script tag (that would be a problem)

Comment: your html also has 3 elements with the id="accordian"

Comment: @happymacarts I know about the 2 elements. I removed one but the behaviour stays the same. As for the scripts, I corrected that. Now it's working, but there's some lag when the panels collapse/toggle. The action is not "smooth" as it should be.

Comment: I modified your recent fiddle again and it [works](https://jsfiddle.net/y5ur0ku6/1/)

Comment: @happymacarts It's not working for me. Here's how my bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js are embedded: `function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
 // Register the script like this for a theme:
 wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-min-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );` Is this correct?

Comment: Last time i will ask. paste your rendered html not in a modified fiddle just paste the freaking code in your question. Do the above files exist on your file server?

Comment: @happymacarts The files exist, yes. I'll add the code in an answer instead as comments are character-limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number of issues with your markup based on the fiddle you posted.

1. you had nested script tags
2. multiple elements with the same ID
3. invalid bootstrap markup

I posted a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y5ur0ku6/1/) resolving those issues

Any additional questions should be placed in a new question DO NOT continue them here.

The changes implemented here will have to backed into your php page

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-description" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-description">Description</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-description" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h2>Product Description</h2>
        <p>description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-additional_information" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-additional_information">
          Additional Information        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-additional_information" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <h2>Additional Information</h2>

        <table class="shop_attributes">
          <tr class="">
            <th>Colour</th>
            <td>
              <p>Pink, Golden, Silver</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="alt">
            <th>Size</th>
            <td>
              <p>UK 10, UK 12, UK 14, UK 8</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- .summary -->
```

Comment: I am unable to paste the entire code in a new answer or add it to my original question due to character limitations. Here's the fiddle though: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/e2vc545g/)

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: OK, somehow it's working now. I have added this to the code: `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` But the movement is not smooth. It doesn't toggle smoothly. The movement looks somehow disrupted. Not sure why?

Comment: happymacarts, I solved the "jumping" effect myself. I added an extra `details` class to the collapsing panels with the following styles: `overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;` And also adjusted the transition of the `.collapsing` class to `height 0.3s` The transition is smooth now. I've marked your answer as the solution. Thanks for your help!